# ¿Por qué no me funciona la validación en el ciclo while con el operador lógico II?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

En este caso tuve un problema para validar el ingreso de datos, no se porque no me funciona bien cuando lo hago. No me funciona el ciclo while del código donde se compara la variable tipo a través del operador lógico ||. Además tengo dudas sobre como ordenar el código en general, ¿esta mas o menos bien como lo hice? ¿o tendía que ordenar de otra manera? Por favor, les agradezco su ayuda. Gracias de antemano

```
let precioUnitario = 0
let tipo = 0
function ingresarProducto() {
  tipo = Number(
    prompt(
      'Ingrese el código del producto. (Rosas: 1, Claveles: 2 o Azucenas: 3 )',
    ),
  )
  
  while (tipo != 1 || tipo != 3 || tipo != 2) {
    prompt(
      'Ingrese código válido. (Rosas: 1, Claveles: 2 o Azucenas: 3 )',
    ).toLowerCase()
  } 
  return tipo
  
}

let flor = ingresarProducto()

function product() {
  if (flor === 1) {
    precioUnitario = 38
  } else if (flor === 2) {
    precioUnitario = 25
  } else if (flor === 3) {
    precioUnitario = 42
  }
  return precioUnitario
}

let cantidad = () =>
  Number(prompt('Ingrese cantidad de flores que quiere en su ramo'))

let precioFlor = product()
let size = cantidad()

console.log('precio unitario ' + precioFlor, 'cantidad ' + size)

function precioR() {
  let precioTotal = precioFlor * size
  return precioTotal
}

let precioRamo = precioR()
let precioEspecial = 0
function descuento() {
  if (size >= 12) {
    precioEspecial = precioRamo - precioRamo * 0.1
  } else {
    precioEspecial = precioRamo
  }
  return precioEspecial
}
let precioDescuento = descuento()

let precioIva = () => precioDescuento * 1.21
let precioFinal = precioIva()
console.log(
  'precio ramo ' + precioRamo,
  'precio con descuento ' + precioDescuento,
  'precio final con IVA ' + precioFinal,
)
alert('Precio final $' + parseInt(precioFinal))
```

Comment: Tu nuevo prompt dentro del while no pasa el valor a la variable tipo... por lo tanto tipo vale siempre lo mismo...

Comment: Entiendo @gbianchi y entonces la solución sería... ¿volver a igualar al variable como tipo dentro del scope del while? es decir tipo = prompt('Ingrese código válido. (Rosas: 1, Claveles: 2 o Azucenas: 3 )',).toLowerCase( )  tal como en la línea anterior?

Comment: De hecho si hago eso e introduzco números que estén fuera del rango de 1 a 3, la operación siempre da como resultado cero(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto el código donde modifique la condición del while, por una opción mas corta, y la reasignación del valor de la variable 'tipo' dentro de dicho while que es lo que faltaría para que funcione la validación del input. Ya que si no se le reasigna un valor por cada entrada, solo guardara el primer valor introducido y nunca saldrá del while. Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

```js
'use strict';

let precioUnitario = 0;
let tipo = 0;

function ingresarProducto() {
    tipo = Number(prompt('Ingrese el código del producto. (Rosas: 1, Claveles: 2 o Azucenas: 3)'));

    while (tipo < 1 || tipo > 3) {
        tipo = Number(prompt('Ingrese código válido. (Rosas: 1, Claveles: 2 o Azucenas: 3 )'));
    }

    return tipo;
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Entiendo gbianchi, ahora lo voy a modificar. No creí necesario hacer una aclaración porque en tu primer comentario esta la aclaración del fallo vista por el usuario que pregunta. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de esa validación en el while puedes poner while(tipo<0 || while > 3)

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: @salva-valladares entiendo que cuando me dices colocar while(tipo<0 || while > 3) en realidad quisiste decir while(tipo < 0 || tipo > 3) pero el problema real es que no funciona tu solución.